# Python: replace numbers in an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following array:

```
array = array([4., 0., 2., 8., 8., 8., 8., 2., 0.])
```

and I would like to replace 0 by 0.5 so to get:

```
array = array([4., 0.5, 2., 8., 8., 8., 8., 2., 0.5])
```

so far I have tried:

```
array.replace(0.5, 0)
```

with little success:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

any idea on how to keep the array format but replace numbers inside it?

cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) to locate the items you want to replace and then just assign the value:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([4., 0., 2., 8., 8., 8., 8., 2., 0.])

array[array == 0.0] = 0.5

print(array)
# [4.  0.5 2.  8.  8.  8.  8.  2.  0.5]
```